# Measure the strength of association between two categorical variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, ordinal-data, association-measure

I'm working with survey data and I have asked 7 questions with predefined responses. As an example, "How do you feel about the meal?" Answers: Satisfied, Ok, Not satisfied. I want to measure the strength of association between two variables. As an example: Strength of association between "Meal satisfaction and Overall satisfaction". My data would be as follow.

[image]

I know we can use "Chi - squared test" to check whether there is a relationship between the two variables or not. Is there any way that I can measure the strength of the relationship? (Like the association between the variables is positive/negative/no relationship).
Thanks in advance.

The data I have is not dichotomous because there are 3 responses for the variables. Hence I think I cannot use either Cramer's V or Polychoric correlation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correlations with categorical variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-categorical-variables). Also check this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/relation-between-two-ordinal-variables?rq=1

Comment: I checked above questions. But the answers are given for 2x2 contingency tables. But I have 3x3 and 3x2 or 2x3 contingency tables. Is there any other method that I can use?

Comment: Correlation only between a pair of categories can have sign (such as between Satisfied and Satisfied; Satisfied and Ok; etc.). See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/74708/3277.

Comment: @ttnphns: Thank you :). So then do I have to calculate correlation between the variables as "compared to Ok, Satisfaction has a positive relationship, compared to Ok, Dissatisfaction has a ..., etc."? Like we do in multi-nomial logistic regression?